# ST_NumInteriorRings not returns zero, is a bug?

Tags: postgis

I am using PostGIS v2.0.3, [the guide](http://postgis.org/docs/ST_NumInteriorRings.html) say that `ST_NumInteriorRings`
"will work with both POLYGON and MULTIPOLYGON types but only looks at the first polygon. Return NULL if there is no polygon in the geometry"... But my query returns only NULLs,

```sql
SELECT gid, 
       ST_NRings(geom) as nrings, 
       ST_NumInteriorRings(geom), ST_NumGeometries(geom) as ngeoms 
FROM t 
WHERE ST_NRings(geom) >1 or ST_NumGeometries(geom)>1
```

for all gid returns `nrings=ngeoms>2` and `ST_NumInteriorRings=NULL`... But I see with my GIS viewer the holes there (!).

---

Example (req. by @JakubKania):

```
SELECT gid, ST_SRID(geom), ST_Geometrytype(geom), 
       ST_NumGeometries(geom) as ngeoms, geom::text
FROM kx.quadrasc 
WHERE ST_NRings(geom) >1 or ST_NumGeometries(geom)>1
LIMIT 2;
  2;31996;"ST_MultiPolygon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

  12;31996;"ST_MultiPolygon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
```

Comment: Post the sample of `geom` please.

Comment: Ok, I edit, is there... It works in your PostgreSQL?

Comment: None of these contains a hole.

Comment: Thanks by the checking. Well, the problem is about the "NULL return", because guide say "Return NULL if there is no polygon in the geometry", and there are a polygon as you see.

Answer (score 2):

MultiPolygons are not Polygons. You need to extract a polygon from the collection before passing it to ST_NumInteriorRings. ST_NRings should be more forgiving, but it will give you the count of both exterior and interior rings. So I guess if you look for cases where ST_NRings > ST_NumGeometries that should turn up instances of MultiPolygons with holes.

Comment: You can extract a polygon using ST_GeometryN or you can dump the collection into a result set using ST_Dump

Comment: Thanks! good tips... Spliting the question into two subquestions: 1) there are a bug? because ST_NumInteriorRings "will work with both POLYGON and MULTIPOLYGON types" and "return NULL if there is no polygon";  2) There are an easy way to check when the MultiPolygon is not a topologically-disjoint set, and its layout behaviour is like a "polygon with holes"?

Comment: No, it's not a bug. It's behaviour I'm not entirely happy with, but the alternative could also be considered confusing: if you run ST_NumInteriorRings on a multi-polygon, what should the answer be? # of interior rings in first polygon? sum of interior rings on all?

Comment: A multipolygon that answers st_numgeometries == 1 is a simple polygon without disjoint members.

Comment: I am reviewing the problem, see answer below...

Answer (score 1):

((this is a Wiki - **you can edit and enhance!**))

**Caution:  this is an old answer, prease review/correct**. The functions are excludent: ST_NumInteriorRings() is for POLYGON and   ST_NumGeometries() for MULTIPOLYGON. Seems that the general solution must be something as:

```sql
 SELECT * FROM t
 WHERE GeometryType(geom)='POLYGON' AND ... ST_NumInteriorRings() ...
 UNION ALL
 SELECT * FROM t
 WHERE GeometryType(geom)!='POLYGON' AND ... ST_NumGeometries() ...
```

### Hole detection in MULTIPOLYGONs

To see only geometries with hules, use the condiction

```sql
  SELECT * FROM t WHERE ST_NRings(geom)>ST_NumGeometries(geom)
```

To check if there are "important hules",

```sql
     ST_NRings(geom) > ST_NumGeometries(geom)
     AND
     round(ST_Area(geom)) < round(ST_Area(
        ST_MakePolygon(ST_ExteriorRing(ST_GeometryN(geom,1)))
     ))
```

this is the "real life" detection. The "non-important hules" (very tiny areas in the case of "ST_Union side effects") can be removed.

### Clean ST_Union

After some analysis I discover that ST_Union produce very tiny areas in some geometries... they have all the area into `ST_GeometryN(geom,1)` and areas of ~`10^-4`...`10^-6` in the other geometries (`ST_GeometryN(geom,n)` with `n>1`).

---

### Answer

About *"ST_NumInteriorRings not returns zero, is a bug?"*

For multipoligon `ST_NumInteriorRings()` **is not a "hule detector"** and the function  (or the guide) **have a bug**: the "NULL return" in the context where geometry is valid and not null.

(edit after PostGIS guide correction)

In nowadays the [Guide](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_NumInteriorRings.html) say:

> Changed: 2.0.0 - in prior versions it would allow passing a MULTIPOLYGON, returning the number of interior rings of first POLYGON.

So, in modern PostGIS you must to decide first what will be the risc of MULTIPOLYGON and its treatment.  To be safe, use `WHERE GeometryType(geom)='POLYGON' AND ...`